# Proving you are a kohen

Tags: rabbis, kohen-priest

When you ask a rabbi to perform a life-cycle ceremony, he will frequently ask for proof that you are Jewish (birth certificates, ketubot, certificates from other rabbis, etc.)  But do you ever have to prove you are a kohen?  What would constitute proof?  Is your word enough?

Comment: To what end do they want to prove that they are a Kohen? The bar for serving in the Temple and for getting the first Aliyah in Shul are different.

Answer (score 3):

But do you ever have to prove you are a kohen?

Proof that one is a Kohen  is relevant for the following things: 
- to be  called to the Torah for the kohen's portion, - to bless the congregation at the *duchan*, - to receive the money for a Pidyon ha'ben of someone's first born son, to not redeem his own first born son, to marry a divorcee [which is forbidden for a kohen].

What would constitute proof? Is your word enough?

The accepted proof to be considered a kohen when there is a question, is testimony from a Torah observant jew that one is a kohen [or sometimes that his father was a kohen]. Sometimes a picture of a forefather's mounument indicating that he was a kohen would  be sufficient.  In each case a component Orthodox Rabbi, should be consulted.

These laws are discussed in Shulchan Aruch Even Ha'Ezev 3. Also see Igros Moshe  Even Ha'Ezer 4/11 and 4/39, and Shevet Ha'Levi 10/226.

Declaring to be a Kohen based on his reliable information, even without testimony, would be sufficient according to some for Torah Reading and *Duchaning*. (Mishnah Berurah 128/1).

Answer (score 0):

Its a delicate thing.. Lets see:

First you and your father and grandfather should be knowned to perfom birkat kohanim (I think it was my Rabbi, an Ab bet din) that sayd that to me. I am a kohen.

Second, its good (my opinion here) to see two things: The last name of the cohen. And (this is very very personal opinion, nothing more) their treats as a person.. Normally Kohanims we are tall.. handsome..big hands.. etc. I can easily recognize a fellow cohen.

For instance I was in Europe not long ago, and someone say here a new person in the synagogue he says is a cohen, why dont u go and talk to him.. Which I did, I looked at him (I thought right away was not a kohen) asked one question or two, and I told him he was not a cohen unfortunatelly (I talked to him i n a good kind manner) because he wasnt a cohen after all, only the last name.

Ah also, since my family is well known cohen family, I asked my Rab that is an av bet din (he is also a Cohen) and that he has known (and his father and grandfather before him) that we are kohanim..I asked him to make me like a certificate of being a kohen. Something saying he saw me performing birkat kohanim to me and to also my father, etc.
With the credentials, stamp, etc. HE is a very important Rab.

Interesting enough after presenting that and other things in Israel, like the ketubah of my parents or grandparents saying that is a kohen, etc. I added to my last name the title Hakohen. So in Israel I am Hakohen and my second last name. (wanna keep it private)

Comment: Dare I guess you are of North African descent?

Comment: I don’t think personal option really counts for psak Halacha. Last names really don’t mean anything. Out of curiosity, though, how did you determine that he wasn’t a Kohen?

Comment: I am not of north african descent. Personal option?. Last name does mean something, if proved before that is a kohen. Double kohanim last names normally means a true kohen ascendence, again if the family is known for being performing kohanim for generations, etc.

Comment: I just knew that he wasnt. I felt it strongly. On the other hand, I can be seen a movie and I could tell if the actor is a jew and a kohen. My father saw a movie for instance and for the main actor (James Caan, which is a kohen) he named after me, the name of his character in the movie. He didnt even know at that time, that james caan was even jew. etc